# How to Dynamically change Chart Range on Drop Down list in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Dynamic Data Range]

I want to change the Chart data as per drop down selected by user.
i can achive this by adding a diff range with vlookup to get the data but i want to implement this dynamically.

Comment: I need help to achieve this with our VBA macros , as i am going to build a Dashboard with multiple kind of Charts .

Comment: Please check this link http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/04/23/interactive-chart-in-excel-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your help. but this is quite difficult to add multiple charts and its ranges in named manager . Still i will try this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey i got a solution for this.

i have created a dynamic range using offset formula in named manager.

i have given the reference of the drop down  year and used match formula to get to the starting position and count the listed data then used the range in the chart.

Thanks.